# Include local javascript source inside String in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, html, webview, javafx

I've got an issue with including a ".js" source inside a String for the Webview in Javafx.

I'm using the CodeEditor approach with Codemirror with the following code:

```
private final String editingTemplate =
        "<!doctype html>" +
                "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css\">" +
                "  <script src=\"http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js\"></script>" +
                "  <script src=\"http://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js\"></script>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<form><textarea id=\"code\" name=\"code\">\n" +
                "${code}" +
                "</textarea></form>" +
                "<script>" +
                "  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(\"code\"), {" +
                "    lineNumbers: true," +
                "    matchBrackets: true," +
                "    mode: \"text/x-java\"" +
                "  });" +
                "</script>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
```

Here I want to replace the ".js" from the CDN with local ".js" files, so a connection is not needed all the time.

```
"  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css\">" +
                "  <script src=\"http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js\"></script>" +
                "  <script src=\"http://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js\"></script>" +
```

I could not find the right syntax to do so, the files are in my src folder as "mypackage/libs/codemirrior.js" for example.

Hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
webEngineInstance.executeScript(editingTemplate);
```